# Can't select text in CreateDialog, but can select a Quantity

Tags: dialog-window

I'm trying to popup a window with a list of strings that I can then individually select and copy to the clipboard. Using `CreateDialog` I can select items formatted as a `Quantity` but not simple text. In the example below I can right click and copy the 1kg entry, but not the Hello text. I tried a few Copyable/Selectable options with no luck. Is there a way to make the text selectable in a `CreateDialog`?

```
CreateDialog[{"Hello", Quantity[1, "Kilograms"]}, ContentSelectable -> True, Copyable -> True, Selectable -> True];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the option [`Deployed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Deployed.html) to `False` seems to do the trick, someone else will have to say *why* though.

```
CreateDialog[
    {
        "Hello",
        Quantity[1, "Kilograms"],
        Style["bob", ShowStringCharacters -> True]
    },
    Deployed -> False, Selectable -> True
]
```

[image]

Comment: Very good! It is odd that "Quantity"s are selectable without that, even with Selectable and Copyable set to False.

Comment: I think that is because the normal formatting for `Quantity` has both a tooltip *and* specially defined right-click behavior, and the dialog doesn't suppress that.